# At what level of the android architecture can I find a devices audio configuration files?

Tags: settings, audio, tablet

I would like to change the granulation of volume steps on an android 10 device. The limited mods on xda don't work on my device (lenovo m8 fhd) What level in the android architecture should I focus on when searching for a configuration file and what file types typically exist for this purpose?

[image: Latest android architecture from source.android.com]

Comment: Is it possible this setting would be device specific? I remember reading somewhere that there is only ever 75 volume steps possible on any device and these are usually devided by a factor of 5 giving 15 steps. This may have originally been defined in C code and compiled so its possible the file Im interested in is a binary file on my device, possibly an .so file making it very difficult to change unless translated to assembly (hopefully well commented)?

If this question is not for stackechange Ill remove after 5 downvotes. Can anyone suggest a forum that may help (not xda)?